# React local props change call dispatch loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component which uses fetch action by dispatching it.
I have a selectbox with pages, which I want to select and then fetch the data again.

I tried to do the `setState` for the page, and then call the `dispatch` from the `componentDidUpdate`, but then I get a loop, because I set the page state, then the `componentDidUpdate` is invoked, dispatching the fetching, and then the items list property is updated, and again `componentDidUpdate` is invoked.

Is there a way to catch the **local state** change only and not the whole state (from the dispatch)? 
Or I just need to use

```
this.page = 5
```

and then invoke the dispatch, instead of

```
this.setState({page: 5})?
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It's hard for me to understand. Show your code.

Comment: You need to use this.state.page (not just this.page)

Comment: Post code sample, cannot give you advice without that